# In Datastage, in oracle connector stage can I use parameters in external sql file?

Tags: sql, etl, data-warehouse, datastage

I am using oracle connector stage and I have selected *"Read select statement from file"* option.
In the sql file I am using a parameter like `where eff_start_date = #eff_start_date#`. I have defined `eff_start_date` parameter in the job and I am also giving its value at run-time, but it is not populating the values and showing invalid character error.
I read somewhere that we can't use parameters in a sql file, so I want to ask is there any workaround for it?

Comment: I've tried various ways with no luck, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Sequence and two job.

- The first job, receive the **eff_star_date** parameter, and do:

  1. Read the sql file (file1), with a Sequential File Stage
  2. Replace the variable string on a Transformer, with the parameter value
  3. Write a new sql file (file2) with replaced string, on Sequential File Stage
- On the second job, there is the Oracle connector with "Read select statement from file" option, that read the complete file (file2)